# How is PDF independent of application software, hardware, and operating systems

Tags: pdf

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF), Portable Document Format presents documents in a manner  independent of application software, hardware, and operating systems. 
And this is really confusing for me. How is that possible (independent of hardware and OS, really!)? Perhaps I did not understand what the statement is saying?

Please explain to me what it means. OR how is PDF any different from any other file format regarding the above statement?

Comment: What part of that don't you understand? It seems pretty clear to me; & evidenced by the sheer number of platforms it works on; viewers & editors for those platforms.

Comment: Well of course it works on Mac, Linux and Windows, but what if we made another OS. are we sure it works on that? also it says independent of application software, what does that even mean? we use adobe, foxit, ... reader to view PDF. does that mean we don't need them?

Comment: May be comparing a different format with PDF will help me understand it.

Comment: How is any application or file type functional across platforms? It comes down to basic parts of what an OS is and what files are.

Answer (score 4):

A PDF (or really, any file) is an arrangement of information stored in digital form consisting of large numbers of individual bits and bytes, and capable of being conveyed on digital storage from one device to another.

Operating Systems are collections of files which are "Executable" that is, they contain series of instructions which work together to interface between the hardware they run on and the software that runs in them.

Software that works upon files essentially "interpret" the information contained in files into elements which work with the Operating System they are being run on.

So, an Android phone requires an application with one set of instructions, while an iPhone requires an application with a different (but likely similar) set of instructions, and the same for computers running Linux, or Windows, or MacOS, each requiring applications with similar but different sets of instructions, all of which contain at their core the ability to read the information contained within a PDF and display it, or convey it to the printing subsystem, or possibly modify the information in the PDF file itself.

The "reason" PDFs display relatively (not perfectly) consistently across multiple systems and OSes is that the information contained within the PDF file type contains clear layout and visual display information. That is how the format was designed from its inception.

Why that's different from other file types is because different file types have different purposes. Some value data, some value unstructured information, some value other things entirely and each are generally designed in a way that makes them consistent IN THEIR OWN WAY AND TO THE THINGS THEY VALUE.

Further, if a PDF viewing application did a poor job of following the instructions contained within the information that comprises the PDF file type, it would not be a very good PDF viewer, and so would not enjoy much support or use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. thought that does not answer my question. perhaps I did not make my question clear.

Comment: @Babydesta - This absolutely answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

The goal for Adobe in the 90s was to create a document format agnostic to the type of computer system it was being read on.  This was desirable as Adobe would then control the base standard.

Also from the Wiki...

The PDF combines three technologies:

- A subset of the PostScript page description programming language, for
  generating the layout and graphics.
- A font-embedding/replacement system to allow fonts to travel with the
  documents.
- A structured storage system to bundle these elements and any
  associated content into a single file, with data compression where
  appropriate.

It's not that any hardware or OS can understand PDFs intrinsically, a computer still needs to be informed of what it is processing.  In PDFs there is a format number that comes in the header ie %PDF-1.7.  This would indicate how to parse accordingly.

Comment: so how is PDF any different from any other files formats?

Comment: @Babydesta that's a different question. Each post in SuperUser is to be a single specific question. If you have another question, please post it. However, I HIGHLY recommend that you do some web searching before asking these sorts of questions. They are exceedingly broad and they come down to very basic aspects of digital files and formats, and there is ample documentation about differing file types available freely online.

Comment: @music2myear, I did not change my question. its still the same, I just added a statement on how I wanted people to answer my question.

Comment: @Babydesta But this answer already has it all. Word for example does not have embedded fonts. PDF is one of very few completely self-contained (text) document formats. You can’t compare it to, say, a JPEG.

Comment: @DanielB, yes this answer gave me a bit ideas, I just wanna make sure I understood it all.

Comment: @Babydesta - Word for instance only existed on two operating systems for the longest time.  Even between those two platforms, what the editor supported, wasn't identical between those two platforms.  There was for a very long time, a huge feature parity with Word, on those two platforms.  Even with open source editors that supported the Word document standard, editors other than Word, did not support every feature that Word supported.  So you could create a document that did not appear exactly the same on Windows, OS X, and Linux

Answer (score 0):

Most document formats start life "the other way around".  An application will be developed, like MS Word, and an associated document format (.e.g., .doc or .docx), will be developed to support its features.  It is "universal" only to the extent that the application developer holds a huge market share, so there is a desire by other developers to be able to handle those files to meet customer expectations of compatibility.  But there is no guarantee that the office suite you want to use on your platform will handle those files, or handle them well, or will keep up with Microsoft's evolution of the format.

The open-source community drives open document standards with associated formats (like .odt).  These are available for any developer to use (it's the standard format for the open-source office suites), or to support (Word supports it).  But again, not every office suite supports it, and your office suite of choice may not be available on every platform.

Even if your office suite is available on all popular platforms and supports the specific format, it doesn't guarantee that someone else's office suite supports it or can render it to look exactly like it looks on your equipment.

Office suites are generally more about communicating than desktop publishing.  They may not provide a mechanism for embedding the specific fonts you use to create the document.  They often rely on font substitutions to achieve a degree of universality in people's ability to open and view a document in essentially the same form as you create it.

The recipient on another platform will see a version rendered with whatever is the similar font on that platform.  The result will be very close, but not exactly the same.  A similar font may not have exactly the same character dimensions or kerning, so lines may not wrap exactly the same.  Usually, this isn't an important difference, but in some situations, it can be.

PDF was developed for the purpose of ensuring that any document could be opened on any platform and look exactly the same.  Its purpose is primarily for viewing or printing the document, not editing it (although they can often be edited, but that defeats the purpose of ensuring that it looks exactly like it was created).

The file format embeds the fonts and layout instructions to recreate an exact copy.  The developer (Adobe) also created software for every platform so that PDF files could be viewed anywhere.

PDF was successful for its intended purpose and adopted as a defacto standard. 
Since the origination of the format, its use and capabilities have been expanded.  Adobe and third party developers have created lots of applications for doing stuff with PDFs.  Many of the major office suites can open and work with PDFs.  Adobe has added features, like the ability to add security so that a PDF can be certified as an unaltered document for legal purposes.  But the fundamental purpose for which PDF was created was different from a word-processing-type application.